# While loops, comparing more than one value

Tags: python, validation, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop

I can understand how to use the while loop perfectly if just to compare it with one thing, for example:

```
x=int(input("Guess my number 1-10"))
while x!=7: 
    print("Wrong!")
    x=int(input("Try again: "))
print("Correct it is 7. ")
```

However, if I want to compare two or more values through while loops (especially if I want to validate something), I would do something like this:

```
number=input("Would you like to eat 1. cake 2. chocolate 3. sweets: ")
while number!= "1" or number != "2" or number != "3":
    number=input("Please input a choice [1,2,3]")
#Some code...
```

When `number` does equal 1, 2 or 3, the program should proceed... but it doesn't, no matter what value I input, the program will be stuck at an infinite loop at line 2-3. I have also tried `while number != "1" or "2" or "3"` and the same infinite loops also occurs. When I try replacing all `or` with `and`, the while loop will only break when `number` equals the first value compared (which in this case is `"1"`).

Is there any way that I can resolve this?

Comment: `number` will never be equal to "1", 2", and "3" at the same time.

Comment: That's why, from the answer which had the correct code: `while number!= "1" and number != "2" and number != "3":` I don't understand why it's `and` not `or`.

Comment: Draw a number line, and highlight everything other than `1`. Now highlight everything other than `2`, and then highlight everything other than `3`. The expression you used will execute the loop when any of its conditions are true (due to the `or` operator), and, as you can see, the entire number line will end up executing the loop in some way.

Comment: [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) states that `"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"`, and `"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"`. You used `(not A) or (not B)` expecting it to mean the same thing as `not (A or B)`.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks :3 That's a bit confusing to wrap my head round lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a condition of `number != '1' or number != '2'`, one of those conditions will always be true, so it'll never break out of the loop. Try `while number not in ('1', '2', '3')` instead.

Comment: Or `while number not in "123":`

Comment: @BrentWashburne Why would that work as "123" is not 1, 2 or 3 but the number 123?

Comment: `in` checks for membership. A string is merely a list of characters, and the character `1` is found in the string `123`.

Comment: @BrentWashburne - your solution works... until the user has 10 things. Since its a non-obvious bug to go from 9 to 10 things, i think a list of strings is better.

Comment: Now that you mention it, even `'123'` could be problematic, because it would allow `'12'`, `'23'`, and `'123'`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you used  `or` instead of `and`. But the `in` operator may be a better choice:

```
number=input("Would you like to eat 1. cake 2. chocolate 3. sweets: ")
while number not in ("1", "2","3"):
    number=input("Please input a choice [1,2,3]")
```